# Visual studio открыть телефон из приложения передав номер телефона?

Tags: c#, uwp

Как из своего приложения позвонить на нужный номер телефона?

Comment: @Bulson не совсем так, в адресной книге не будет этого номера( не знакомый) просто надо совершить звонок на номер по которому клацают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот есть готовый [пример](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PhoneCall) можете скачать и посмотреть, что как.

Comment: А по проще есть где нибудь?)

Comment: Проще это как? Чтоб до 5 строчек кода было ;)? Ну серьезно, вы можете поставить точки остановки и построчно пройти в дебагере и посмотреть что и как и где. Все так делают. Даже профи когда приходят в новый проект работать.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за совет)